# ¿Cómo combinar dataframes (con el mismo nombre) de diferentes listas?

Tags: r, lista, dataframe, union

Tengo dos listas: una lista contiene un dataframe por cada provincia del país, en que se indica la cantidad de **enfermos** por grupo de edad:

```
GrupoEdad  <- c("0-20","21-65","65 y más")
Enfermos <- c(15,52,65)

Provincia1 <- data.frame(GrupoEdad,Enfermos)

GrupoEdad2  <- c("0-20","21-65","65 y más")
Enfermos2 <- c(8,38,55)

Provincia2 <- data.frame(GrupoEdad2,Enfermos2) %>%
  rename("GrupoEdad" = "GrupoEdad2", "Enfermos" = "Enfermos2")

lista1 <- list(Provincia1,Provincia2)
```

La otra contiene un dataframe por cada provincia del país, en que se indica la **población** por grupo de edad:

```
GrupoEdad  <- c("0-20","21-65","65 y más")
Poblacion <- c(11000,40000,5600)

Provincia1 <- data.frame(GrupoEdad,Poblacion)

GrupoEdad2  <- c("0-20","21-65","65 y más")
Poblacion2 <- c(5400,29000,4000)

Provincia2 <- data.frame(GrupoEdad2,Poblacion2) %>%
  rename("GrupoEdad" = "GrupoEdad2", "Poblacion" = "Poblacion2")

lista2 <- list(Provincia1,Provincia2)
```

Todos los dataframe tienen una variable en común: “GrupoEdad”.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer un left_join entre los dataframe en cada lista correspondientes a cada provincia? La idea es que, para cada provincia, obtenga un dataframe tanto con la cantidad de enfermos como con la población por grupo de edad, para poder calcular tasas.

La situación a la cual la quiero aplicar este concepto es un poco más compleja, con más dataframes de mayor tamaño, pero básicamente es esto lo que tendría que resolver.

Comment: para un left join puedes ocupar ```merge(x = Provincia1, y = Provincia2, by = "GrupoEdad", all.x = TRUE)``` aunque si quieres una explicación más detallada, puedes ver esta otra [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Pero yo no quier unir Provincia1 y Provincia2; quiero unir Provincia1 de la lista1 con Provincia1 de la lista 2, y Provincia2 de lista1 con Provincia2 de lista 2.

Comment: El principal problema, es que como lo tienes definido, las listas no tienen información de la provincia, más allá que sepas que la lista Provincia1 es efectivamente la Provincia1, no tienes forma de hacerlo de modo genérico

Comment: ¿Es decir que para empezar, debería asignarle nombres a los dataframe dentro de las listas? Voy a intentar averiguar cómo hacer eso. Una vez que eso esté definido, ¿la unión entre los dataframe con el mismo nombre en las diferentes listas puede hacerse de manera sencilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL primer problema es que tienes `data.frames` que han perdido la información del nombre de la provincia, por lo que esto sería lo primero que trabajaría. La forma más sencilla podría ser darle el nombre a cada lista, por ejemplo:

```
lista1 <- list(Prov1=Provincia1, Prov2=Provincia2)
lista2 <- list(Prov1=Provincia1, Prov2=Provincia2)
```

Otra forma sería que el dato ya te llegue como columna.

Hecho esto, puedes usar `tidyverse` y varias de sus funciones para:

1. Unir cada `data.frame` en uno único y transformar el nombre de la lista en columna
2. Agrupar por provincia y grupo de edad
3. Sumarizamos cada columnas

---

```
library(tidyverse)

c(lista1, lista2) %>% 
  map_df(rbind, .id = 'provincia') %>% 
  group_by(provincia , GrupoEdad) %>% 
  summarize(Enfermos = sum(Enfermos, na.rm = TRUE),
            Poblacion = sum(Poblacion, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   provincia [2]
  provincia GrupoEdad Enfermos Poblacion
  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Prov1     0-20            15     11000
2 Prov1     21-65           52     40000
3 Prov1     65 y más        65      5600
4 Prov2     0-20             8      5400
5 Prov2     21-65           38     29000
6 Prov2     65 y más        55      4000
```

Nota: `.id = 'provincia'` sirve para capturar el dato de la provincia desde el nombre de la lista, si este dato ya llega como columna no usar este parámetro.